# How to add a CheckBox in a Header cell in a DataGridView

Tags: mysql, vb.net

How can I add a `CheckBox` in the `Header`? It will then select all the `CheckBoxes`.
Also, how can I align the `CheckBox` in center.

Here's my Code:

```vb
Private Sub frm_reciev_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    Dim chkbox As New DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn

    With chkbox
        .Width = 60
    End With

    With DataGridView1
        .Columns.Add(chkbox)
        .RowHeadersVisible = False
    End With
End Sub
```

Heres the image:

[image]

Comment: There is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8906575/checkbox-in-the-header-of-a-datagridview-in-any-column) but it's in C#, are you able to translate in to VB.Net ?

Comment: I'm still new in vb.net, i will find it hard to convert it in vb.net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i remember well :

```
dataGridView1.Columns[ColumnName].DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
```

Answer (score 0):

To create a customised header cell (one containing the `CheckBox`, and supporting functionality) you will need to create three classes.

1. DataGridViewCheckBoxHeaderCell.vb

   ```
   Imports System.Windows.Forms.VisualStyles
   Public Class DataGridViewCheckBoxHeaderCell
       Inherits DataGridViewColumnHeaderCell
       Public Event CheckBoxClicked As EventHandler(Of DataGridViewCheckBoxHeaderCellEventArgs)

       Private Property CheckBoxLocation As Point
       Private Property CheckBoxSize As Size
       Private Property IsChecked As Boolean
       Private Property CellLocation As Point
       Private Property CheckBoxState As CheckBoxState

       Protected Overrides Sub Paint(graphics As Graphics,
                             clipBounds As Rectangle,
                             cellBounds As Rectangle,
                             rowIndex As Integer,
                             dataGridViewElementState As DataGridViewElementStates,
                             value As Object,
                             formattedValue As Object,
                             errorText As String,
                             cellStyle As DataGridViewCellStyle,
                             advancedBorderStyle As DataGridViewAdvancedBorderStyle,
                             paintParts As DataGridViewPaintParts)
           MyBase.Paint(graphics, clipBounds, cellBounds, rowIndex, dataGridViewElementState, value, formattedValue, errorText, cellStyle, advancedBorderStyle, paintParts)

           CheckBoxSize = CheckBoxRenderer.GetGlyphSize(graphics, CheckBoxState.UncheckedNormal)

           Dim x As Integer = cellBounds.Location.X + (cellBounds.Width / 2) - (CheckBoxSize.Width / 2)
           Dim y As Integer = cellBounds.Location.Y + (cellBounds.Height / 2) - (CheckBoxSize.Height / 2)

           CheckBoxLocation = New Point(x, y)

           CellLocation = cellBounds.Location

           CheckBoxState = If(IsChecked, CheckBoxState.CheckedNormal, CheckBoxState.UncheckedNormal)

           CheckBoxRenderer.DrawCheckBox(graphics, CheckBoxLocation, CheckBoxState)
       End Sub

       Protected Overrides Sub OnMouseClick(e As DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs)
           Dim p As Point = New Point(e.X + CellLocation.X, e.Y + CellLocation.Y)

           If (p.X >= CheckBoxLocation.X AndAlso
               p.X <= CheckBoxLocation.X + CheckBoxSize.Width AndAlso
               p.Y >= CheckBoxLocation.Y AndAlso
               p.Y <= CheckBoxLocation.Y + CheckBoxSize.Height) Then

               IsChecked = Not IsChecked
               Dim eventArgs As New DataGridViewCheckBoxHeaderCellEventArgs(e.ColumnIndex, IsChecked)
               OnCheckBoxClicked(eventArgs)
               Me.DataGridView.InvalidateCell(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex)
           End If

           MyBase.OnMouseClick(e)
       End Sub

       Protected Overridable Sub OnCheckBoxClicked(eventArgs As DataGridViewCheckBoxHeaderCellEventArgs)
           RaiseEvent CheckBoxClicked(Me, eventArgs)
       End Sub
   End Class
   ```
2. DataGridViewCheckBoxEventArgs.vb

   ```
   Public Class DataGridViewCheckBoxHeaderCellEventArgs
       Inherits EventArgs

       Public Sub New(columnIndex As Integer, isChecked As Boolean)
           Me.ColumnIndex = columnIndex
           Me.IsChecked = isChecked
       End Sub

       Public Property ColumnIndex As Integer
       Public Property IsChecked As Boolean
   End Class
   ```
3. DataGridViewCustomCheckBoxColumn.vb

   ```
   Public Class DataGridViewCustomCheckBoxColumn
       Inherits DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn

       Public Sub New()
           MyBase.New()

           MyBase.CellTemplate = New DataGridViewCheckBoxCell()

           Dim datagridViewCheckBoxHeaderCell As New DataGridViewCheckBoxHeaderCell()

           Me.HeaderCell = datagridViewCheckBoxHeaderCell
           Me.Width = 50

           AddHandler datagridViewCheckBoxHeaderCell.CheckBoxClicked, AddressOf datagridViewCheckBoxHeaderCell_OnCheckBoxClicked
       End Sub

       Private Sub datagridViewCheckBoxHeaderCell_OnCheckBoxClicked(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCheckBoxHeaderCellEventArgs)
           DataGridView.RefreshEdit()

           For Each row As DataGridViewRow In Me.DataGridView.Rows
               If (Not row.Cells(e.ColumnIndex).ReadOnly) Then
                   row.Cells(e.ColumnIndex).Value = e.IsChecked
               End If
           Next

           DataGridView.RefreshEdit()
       End Sub

       Public Overrides Property CellTemplate As DataGridViewCell
           Get
               Return MyBase.CellTemplate
           End Get
           Set
               ' Ensure that the cell used for the template is a DataGridViewCheckBoxCell.
               If (Value IsNot Nothing) Then
                   Throw New InvalidCastException("Must be a DataGridViewCheckBoxCell")
               End If

               MyBase.CellTemplate = Value
           End Set
       End Property
   End Class
   ```

and finally a demo/testing form to illustrate how it all works together. After dropping a `DataGridView` on to your form, use this code to quickly fill it with test data comprised of four columns.

```
    Public Class Form1
        Public Sub New()

            ' This call is required by the designer.
            InitializeComponent()

            ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.

            InitialiseData()

            DataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = False
            DataGridView1.Columns.Clear()

            ' This is the important line that will add a customised Checkbox colum to the DataGridView
            Dim checkedColumn As New DataGridViewCustomCheckBoxColumn()
            checkedColumn.DataPropertyName = "Checked"
            DataGridView1.Columns.Add(checkedColumn)

            Dim nameColumn As New DataGridViewTextBoxColumn()
            nameColumn.DataPropertyName = "Name"
            DataGridView1.Columns.Add(nameColumn)

            Dim addressColumn As New DataGridViewTextBoxColumn()
            addressColumn.DataPropertyName = "Address"
            DataGridView1.Columns.Add(addressColumn)

            Dim phoneColumn As New DataGridViewTextBoxColumn()
            phoneColumn.DataPropertyName = "Phone"
            DataGridView1.Columns.Add(phoneColumn)

            DataGridView1.DataSource = People
        End Sub

        Private People As DataTable

        Private Sub InitialiseData()
            People = New DataTable()
            People.Columns.Add("Checked", GetType(Boolean))
            People.Columns.Add("Name", GetType(String))
            People.Columns.Add("Address", GetType(String))
            People.Columns.Add("Phone", GetType(String))

            People.Rows.Add(True, "J1", "Address1", "123")
            People.Rows.Add(False, "J2", Nothing, "456")
            People.Rows.Add(True, "J3", "Address3", "789")
            People.Rows.Add(False, "J4", "Address4", "147")
            People.Rows.Add(DBNull.Value, "J5", "Address5", "258")
        End Sub
    End Class
```

Comment: Please, let me know if anything is unclear or you need further elaboration/explanation

Comment: @JonathanBatac Glad to hear it helps. If you find it's sufficient to answer your question, don't forget to accept as the answer. It will also help other people with the same question as yours. See [What does it mean when an answer is "accepted"?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)